# How to split list of arrays in ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to Angular and have a split issue at moment.

I want to split Class Subjects into two columns called `subject ID` and `Name` by using split("--" and ";"). However, I have no idea about how to do it within `ng-repeat` table.

This is what the table looks like now:

[image: screen shots]

What I want is 3 column table more like this:

```
username  subject ID  Subject Name
```

HTML CODE

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Class Subjects</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="studentsMember in currentPageElements">
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
        <td>{{studentsMember.username}}</td>
        <td>{{studentsMember.class_subject}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Controller

```
function listStudentClassCtrl($scope,UserManager,SchoolService,SingleRequestHandler,TableService) {
    $scope.items = {};

    var listStudentClassDefer;
    if(angular.isUndefined(listStudentClassDefer))
    {
      $scope.loading = true;
      listStudentClassDefer = SingleRequestHandler.promiseRequest('ListClassesBySchoolId', {inst_id: SchoolService.getCurrentSchool().institution_id, user_type: 10});
      listStudentClassDefer.promise.then(
        function(data){
            console.info("ListUsers - data ",data);
          $scope.staff = data.response;
          TableService.elements = $scope.staff;
        }, 
        function(httpError){
          console.log(httpError);
          $scope.alert.stat = true;
        })
        .finally(function(){
          $scope.loading = false;
        });
    }
}
```

Data response format

```
 "response":[  
   {  

      "username":"bingowere ",
      "class_subject":"8GEO 3 -- SocialSciences; 8SCI 3 -- Unknown; 8JAP 1 -- Unknown; 8PDH 4 -- Unknown"
   },
   {  
      "username":"letbingo ",
      "class_subject":"8GEO 2 -- SocialSciences; 8RC 6 -- SocialSciences; 8PDH 1 -- Unknown"
   }]
```

Comment: Don't do it in the template. Do it in your controller or service JavaScript code. Or better, fix the backend to make it returned structured JSON data, instead of a string to split.

Comment: Thks for your suggestion, but how to do it with controller?

Comment: @QingXu No need to do it in the controller (it's too simple a change), just tweak your HTML...  (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this might be closer to what Qing Xu is after.

[image]

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="listStudentClassCtrl">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Subject ID</th>
        <th>Subject Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="studentsMember in currentPageElements">
      <tr ng-repeat="classSubject in studentsMember.class_subject.split(';')">
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
        <td>{{studentsMember.username}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="SubjectIDName in classSubject.split('--')">{{SubjectIDName}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

JavaScript/AngularJS Controller:

```
app.controller('listStudentClassCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.currentPageElements = [{
    "username": "bingowere ",
    "class_subject": "8GEO 3 -- SocialSciences; 8SCI 3 -- Unknown; 8JAP 1 -- Unknown; 8PDH 4 -- Unknown"
  }, {
    "username": "letbingo ",
    "class_subject": "8GEO 2 -- SocialSciences; 8RC 6 -- SocialSciences; 8PDH 1 -- Unknown"
  }];
});
```

Here's a link to a working Plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit/zcDHa6W8hRUKNMOgKnYZ?p=preview

Comment: Great! Thank you! This is exactly what I want !

Comment: Excellent.  Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

***NB: This answer assumes you cannot update the server response to pre-process this response for you into a useful format***

You're best to do this by processing your data before (or immediately after) you call `$scope.staff = data.response;` You could do this with something like the following code:

```
var splitClassSubjectIntoIdAndName(response){
    var processedResponse = [];
    for(var x = 0, len = response.length; x < len; x++){
        var responseItem = response[x]; // pass it all existing data
        responseItem.subjects = [];
        var idAndName = response[x].class_subject.split('; ');
        for(var y = 0, lenY = idAndName.lenght; y < lenY; y++){
            var splitIdAndName = idAndName[y].split(' -- ');
            responseItem.subjects.push({
                subject_id: splitIdAndName[0],
                subject_name: splitIdAndName[1]
            });
        }
    }
    return processedResponse;
}
$scope.staff = splitClassSubjectIntoIdAndName(data.response);
```

Then later in your view code, you would `ng-repeat="staffMember in staff"` and within that `ng-repeat="subject in staffMember.subjects"`.

Ultimately, the best option would be to have the data come down from your server in a useful format, this way each client doesnt have to process the response, and you can leverage caching to speed up your calls :)